# Foo() = () = () => {} vs foo = () => {}

Tags: javascript

what is the difference between

`Foo() = () = () => {}`

and

`Foo = () => () => {}`

and

`Foo = () => {}`

A colleague pointed it out and i have no clue what the top one is.

Comment: The top one is not valid syntax.

Comment: 1 is invalid. 2 is a function that returns a function that returns an object and 3 is a function that returns an object

Comment: I thought the top one was invalid never seen it before

Comment: @haim770 Isn't the second rather a function returning a noop function, and the third a noop function? Returing an object would be `Foo = () => () => ({})` and `Foo = () => ({})`

Comment: @Tholle, Actually yes. You're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st one =>

```
Foo() = () = () => {
```

This is not a valid syntax and it will throw the following error when you run it

> Invalid left-hand side in assignment

2nd one =>

```
Foo = () => () => {}
```

In this `foo` is assigned as a function which itself is returning a function which again is a blank function. When you will console `typeof Foo` you will get

> "function"

3rd One =>

```
Foo = () => {}
```

Is simply assigning Foo as a function, again When you will console `typeof Foo` you will get

> "function"